# Button keeping the style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever i press one of the buttons they change to .active css (this is good)  but the problem is : when i click another button , they change to the .active css (which is good), but the previous button keeps their .active css, i dont want that , after i click another i want them to take the default css and just the button that is pressed to take the .active css
HTML

```
<button id="btn1">a</button>
<button id="btn2">b</button>
<button id="btn3">c</button>
<button id="btn4">d3</button>
<button id="btn5">e 4</button>
<button id="btn6">f 5</button>
<button id="btn7">g 6</button>
<button id="btn8">h 7</button>
<div class="divToHide" id="story">story</div>
<div class="divToHide" id="z1">1</div>
<div class="divToHide" id="z2">2</div>
<div class="divToHide" id="z3">3</div>
<div class="divToHide" id="z4">4</div>
<div class="divToHide" id="z5">5</div>
<div class="divToHide" id="z6">6</div>
<div class="divToHide" id="z7">7</div>
```

CSS

```
#z1, #z2, #z3, #z4, #z5, #z6, #z7 {
    display: none;
}
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {

    $('#btn1').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
    });

    $('#btn2').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#z1').fadeToggle(700);
    });

    $('#btn3').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#z2').fadeToggle(700);
    });

    $('#btn4').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#z3').fadeToggle(700);
    });

    $('#btn5').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#z4').fadeToggle(700);
    });

    $('#btn6').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#z5').fadeToggle(700);
    });

    $('#btn7').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#z6').fadeToggle(700);
    });

    $('#btn8').on('click', function () {
        $('.divToHide').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#z7').fadeToggle(700);
    });

});
```

Comment: General tip: Don't repeat jQuery code (especially as it already uses `this`). Apply a class to all buttons and data-drive any additional requirements (like your target elements) from `data-` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in line 2:

```
 // After This Line:
 // $(function () {

 $("button").click(function () {$('button').removeClass('active')});
```

The above code will `remove active` class for all `buttons` when you click on one of the buttons.

Answer (score 4):

General tip: Don't repeat jQuery code (especially as it already uses this). Apply a class to all buttons (to allow group selection) and data-drive any additional requirements (like your target elements) from data- attributes.

For this example I just surrounded the buttons in a div so they could all be selected together.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pEA9R/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        // Fetch the data-id attribute value for our target element
        var target = $this.data('id');

        // remove the active class from all buttons
        $('#buttons button').removeClass('active');

        // Hide all target divs
        $('.divToHide').hide();

        // highlight the clicked item
        $this.addClass('active');

        // Show the required div
        $('#' + target).fadeToggle(400);
    });

});
```

This also uses the delegated version of `on`. So you could make it listen on the parent of the buttons, rather than `document` to make is slightly more efficient:

```
    $('#button').on('click', 'button', function () {
```

Delegated events are great because they only create a single handler connection, and even support dynamically added items (added somewhere within the target ancestor).

Comment: I like this answer, it is what I was trying to describe, but it has the code and JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function that removes all active class css from your html.  Place the following statement in that function and call it from each button click event. `$("button").removeClass('active');`

**EDIT:**
It would be best to wrap your buttons in a div with an id say.. buttonWrapper and use the following code instead. `$("buttonWrapper > button").removeClass('active');`